# Como puedo solucionar este error en Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

Alguien podría ayudarme con este error en Codeigniter 3.0.6 con el HMVC, al parecer no me detecta el controlador dentro del modulo. Estas son mis lineas de código.

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://web.com/project/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Árbol de mi proyecto

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | modules
| | | login
| | | | models
| | | | | ...
| | | | views
| | | | | ...
| | | | controllers
| | | | | home.php
|.htaccess
```

Mi resultado del error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca debes alterar el orden de las carpetas que viene por defecto en CodeIgniter.

En tu árbol aparece una carpeta modules que no viene por defecto. La estructura debe ser:

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | models
| | | ...
| | views
| | | ...
| | controllers
| | | home.php
|.htaccess
```

De modo que controllers, models y views se encuentran en la carpeta application. De esta forma, tu controlador por defecto se puede establecer

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Como indica Alfonso Carrasco, ya que la ruta especificada en el parámetro default_controller ha de ser relativa al directorio application/controllers de tu proyecto.

Sin embargo, se pueden crear directorios para estructurar el código de manera organizada. Por ejemplo, se pueden crear directorios en la carpeta views para poder distinguir vistas de distintos apartados del sitio web. La referencia a una vista en una carpeta podría ser:

```
$this->load->view('user/profile');
```

Esto cargaría la vista "profile" alojada en la carpeta views/user.

Answer (score 0):

En tu árbol indicas que el controlador esta directo en raíz, pero en tu `default_controller` le estas indicando que lo tienes dentro de una carpeta llamada: `/login`.

Tu árbol:

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | ..
| | modules
| | | login
| | | | models
| | | | | ...
| | | | views
| | | | | ...
| | | | controllers
| | | | | home.php <- Aquí indicas que la carpeta; login no existe.
```

Debes cambiar lo siguiente:

`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

y listo, deberá funcionar.

Comment: La carpeta login si existe, y esta debajo de "modules"

Comment: Pero no debe estar ahí debe estar como te comente.

Comment: Ya lo intente poniendo el controlador solo, el modulo solo, etc.. sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Cabe resaltar que **en mi localhost si funciona**, pero cuando lo subi al servidor no...

Comment: Y en server tienes la misma estructura?.

Comment: Si, tiene la misma estructura, pero no funciona en el servidor... solo en el localhost :S!

Answer (score 0):

Para crear módulos o versiones en *CodeIgniter* y que funcione tu código debes de crear las carpetas dentro de *Controller* y no modificar el orden original.

Ejemplo:

Tu lo tienes así:

```
project 
| config
| | | ..
| | modules
| | | login
| | | | models
| | | | | ...
| | | | views
| | | | | ...
| | | | controllers
| | | | | home.php
```

Debe ser así:

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | models
| | | ...
| | views
| | | ...
| | **controllers** 
| | | login
| | | | home.php
|.htaccess
```